# application is crashing while user exits from fullscreen mode in mpmovieplayer

Tags: ipad

hi folks we do have a video file in our application,every thing is going fine except one,i.e the application crashes when user exits from fullscreen mode while the movie is playing and also when we pause the movie in fullscreen mode and minimize it,the video starts from the beginning i tried searching whether there is any notification available to notify but of no use plz help me out.thx in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

atlast after studying a lot about mpmovieplayer class refernece i could find the answer for my question which i had posted yesterday.The reason for that was i was not able to provide all the available notifications i need, now i had mentioned each and every notification for entering into full screen,exit the fullscfreen and also playbackfinished now its working fine.The only problem is when i press the toggle screen it maximizes perfectly and plays  from the current playbacktime but that not the case when i minimize the screen the video plays from the begining.